# Consulta doble MYSQL

Tags: mysql

**TABLA SERVICIO_MED_LEG**

```
id_formulario_8
fecha_solicitud
nombre_usuario
correo_usuario
id_establecimiento_1    FK A ESTABLECIMIENTO ID
id_establecimiento_2    FK A ESTABLECIMIENTO ID
```

**TABLA ESTABLECIMIENTO**

```
ID
NAME
```

**CONSULTA**

```
SELECT id_formulario_8, fecha_solicitud, nombre_usuario, correo_usuario, e.name as nombre_establecimiento FROM servicio_med_leg f, establecimiento e WHERE f.id_establecimiento_1=e.id
```

Me funciona bien y muestra los datos que necesito, pero ahora estoy intentando agregar un segundo establecimiento (id_establecimiento_2) a la misma consulta.

En la estructura de mi tabla servicio_med_leg existen dos campos id_establecimiento_1 y id_establecimiento_2, ambos son llaves foraneas a la tabla establecimiento, necesito una consulta para mostrar ambos datos.
La consulta que mostre al principio funciona bien para un solo campo, pero no se como hacerlo para los 2 campos.

Comment: ESto va a mostrar todos los establecimientos que tengas, siempre y cuando esten en las dos tablas...

Comment: Creo que seria conveniente que crearas una tabla de detalle para relacionar los establecimientos donde `servicio_med_leg` trabaja (?)

Comment: Modifique la pregunta, ahora quizas se entienda mejor

Comment: Se va a entender muchísimo mejor si nos **muestras** la estructura de las tablas involucradas, unos pocos datos de prueba y el resultado esperado.

Comment: agregue las estructuras de las tablas y la consulta que estoy haciendo

Comment: Porque razon hay dos campos establecimiento?

Comment: porque con el formulario que debo trabajar, esta establecido de esa manera, un establecimiento de preferencia 1 y un establecimiento de preferencia 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La consulta que realizas no es muy estándar puesto que utilizas dos tablas y nos las relacionas, deberías hacerlo con un `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT e.name as nombre_Establecimiento 
FROM servicio_med_leg f
INNER JOIN establecimiento e on f.id_establecimiento_1 = e.id and f.id_establecimiento_2 = e.id
```

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, aunque ejecute la consulta pero no me muestra nada.

Comment: He eliminado el `WHERE` de la consulta

Comment: Ahora salvo que funcione mal la tabla, dificil que el id sea igual a dos valores que deberian ser diferentes...

Comment: Gracias, quitando el where me muestra los datos. Pero tengo una duda mas, yo estoy consultando por los establecimientos de un solo registro y con la consulta obtengo 2 registros (1 para cada establecimiento). se podrá traerlos en un solo registro???

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres que se muestren los nombres del establecimiento 1 y 2 tendrías que hacer una consulta con un INNER JOIN pero agregando dos veces la tabla establecimientos.

```
SELECT s.id_formulario_8, s.fecha_solicitud, s.nombre_usuario, s.correo_usuario,
e1.nombre AS 'establecimiento 1', e2.nombre AS 'establecimiento 2'
FROM SERVICIO_MED_LEG AS s 
INNER JOIN establecimientos AS e1 ON s.id_establecimiento_1 = e1.id
INNER JOIN establecimientos AS e2 ON s.id_establecimiento_2 = e2.id;
```

[image: Tabla establecimientos]

[image: Este seria el resultado]

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas como te dicen arriba hacer join con dos tablas, si existe la posibilidad de que un servicio solo este en un establecimiento deberías hacer un left join cosa que si un establecimiento no tiene datos te traiga valores nulos pero te traiga los datos del servicio.

```
SELECT id_formulario_8, fecha_solicitud, nombre_usuario, correo_usuario,e.name as nombre_establecimiento 
FROM servicio_med_leg f left join establecimiento e1 on (f.id_establecimiento_1 = e1.id)
left join establecimiento e2 on (f.id_establecimiento_2 = e2.id)
```